# Threaded Mandelbrot program C++

Tags: c++, mandelbrot

To preface this: I'm currently a first-year student who was allowed to enroll in some second-year classes. Because of this, I'm currently wrangling a language (C++) that I haven't really had the time to learn (First-years mostly learn C#), so this code might not be pretty.

Our assignment is twofold. First, we need to write a program that outputs a Mandelbrot image in a PPM. To achieve this, I've followed a Youtube tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=entjSp3LIfQ).

The second part of the assignment is to make the program multithreaded. Essentially, the program is supposed to use 4 threads that each draw a quarter of the image.

To this end I have altered the code from the video tutorial, and converted the main to a method. Now, I'm trying to properly make the first quarter of the image. I figured the way to do this was to adjust

```
        for (int y = 0; y < imageHeight; y++) //Rows!
        {
           for (int x = 0; x < imageWidth; x++) //Columns! (pixels in every row)
           {
```

to

```
        for (int y = 0; y < halfHeight; y++) //Rows!
        {
           for (int x = 0; x < halfWidth; x++) //Columns! (pixels in every row)
           {
```

However, instead of drawing the top left quarter as I suspected, the program drew along the full width, repeating itself after the halfway mark of the image width was reached, and only drew along a quarter of the height
[(see image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auOtf.png)

As I like to learn from my mistakes, I'd love to know what exactly is going wrong here.

Thank you for helping a programming greenhorn out :)

Full program code below.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int imageWidth = 512, imageHeight = 512, maxN = 255, halfWidth = 256, halfHeight = 256;
double minR = -1.5, maxR = 0.7, minI = -1.0, maxI = 1.0;
std::ofstream f_out("output_image.ppm");

int findMandelbrot(double cr, double ci, int max_iterations)
{
    int i = 0;
    double zr = 0.0, zi = 0.0;
    while (i < max_iterations && zr * zr + zi * zi < 4.0)
    {
        double temp = zr * zr - zi * zi + cr;
        zi = 2.0 * zr * zi + ci;
        zr = temp;
        i++;
    }

    return i;
}

double mapToReal(int x, int imageWidth, double minR, double maxR)
{
    double range = maxR - minR;
    return x * (range / imageWidth) + minR;
}

double mapToImaginary(int y, int imageHeight, double minI, double maxI)
{
    double range = maxI - minI;
    return y * (range / imageHeight) + minI;
}

void threadedMandelbrot() 
{
    for (int y = 0; y < halfHeight; y++) //Rows!
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < halfWidth; x++) //Columns! (pixels in every row)
        {
            //... Find the real and imaginary values of c, corresponding
            //      to that x,y pixel in the image
            double cr = mapToReal(x, imageWidth, minR, maxR);
            double ci = mapToImaginary(y, imageHeight, minI, maxI);
            //... Find the number of iterations in the Mandelbrot formula
            //      using said c.
            int n = findMandelbrot(cr, ci, maxN);

            //... Map the resulting number to an RGB value.
            int r = (n % 256);
            int g = (n % 256);
            int b = (n % 256);

            //... Output it to the image
            f_out << r << " " << g << " " << b << " ";
        }
        f_out << std::endl;
    }

}


int main()
{
    //Initializes file
    f_out << "P3" << std::endl;
    f_out << imageWidth << " " << imageHeight << std::endl;
    f_out << "256" << std::endl;

    //For every pixel...
    threadedMandelbrot();
    f_out.close();
    std::cout << "Helemaal klaar!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Output the coordinates of each point that is calculated, it should become obvious where your error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are calculating only a quarter of the image, so you have to set the dimension of that to `halfHeight`, `halfWidth` or fill the file with zeroes. When the image viewer reads the file, it shows two lines of it in a single line of pixels untill it reaches the end of the file, at a quarter of the picture height.

To fix the problem you just have to calculate the other three quarters of the image, but I suggest you to seperate the calc function from the file writing function: do the threaded calcs putting the result in an array (`std::array` or `std::vector`), look up the right color and then write to file.

Comment: Thank you for your help! This was just the answer I needed. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a multi-threaded implementation of Mandelbrot. Instead of scanning X and Y in nested loops, I scan pixels from 0 to width*height. The Mandelbrot worker thread then calculates the logical and real coordinates of the pixel. Here is a subset of the code...

```
// Worker thread for processing the Mandelbrot algorithm
DWORD WINAPI MandelbrotWorkerThread(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    // This is a copy of the structure from the paint procedure.
    // The address of this structure is passed with lParam.
    typedef struct ThreadProcParameters
    {
        int       StartPixel;
        int       EndPixel;
        int       yMaxPixel;
        int       xMaxPixel;
        uint32_t* BitmapData;
        double    dxMin;
        double    dxMax;
        double    dyMin;
        double    dyMax;
    } THREADPROCPARAMETERS, *PTHREADPROCPARAMETERS;
    PTHREADPROCPARAMETERS P;
    P = (PTHREADPROCPARAMETERS)lpParam;

    // Algorithm obtained from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set.

    double x0, y0, x, y, xtemp;

    int iteration;

    // Loop for each pixel in the slice.
    for (int Pixel = P->StartPixel; Pixel < P->EndPixel; ++Pixel)
    {
        // Calculate the x and y coordinates of the pixel.
        int xPixel = Pixel % P->xMaxPixel;
        int yPixel = Pixel / P->xMaxPixel;

        // Calculate the real and imaginary coordinates of the point.
        x0 = (P->dxMax - P->dxMin) / P->xMaxPixel * xPixel + P->dxMin;
        y0 = (P->dyMax - P->dyMin) / P->yMaxPixel * yPixel + P->dyMin;

        // Initial values.
        x = 0.0;
        y = 0.0;
        iteration = 0;

        // Main Mandelbrot algorithm. Determine the number of iterations
        // that it takes each point to escape the distance of 2. The black
        // areas of the image represent the points that never escape. This
        // algorithm is supposed to be using complex arithmetic, but this
        // is a simplified separation of the real and imaginary parts of
        // the point's coordinate. This algorithm is described as the
        // naive "escape time algorithm" in the WikiPedia article noted.

        while (x * x + y * y <= 2.0 * 2.0 && iteration < max_iterations)
        {
            xtemp = x * x - y * y + x0;
            y = 2 * x * y + y0;
            x = xtemp;
            ++iteration;
        }

        // When we get here, we have a pixel and an iteration count.
        // Lookup the color in the spectrum of all colors and set the
        // pixel to that color. Note that we are only ever using 1000
        // of the 16777215 possible colors. Changing max_iterations uses
        // a different pallette, but 1000 seems to be the best choice.
        // Note also that this bitmap is shared by all 64 threads, but
        // there is no concurrency conflict as each thread is assigned
        // a different region of the bitmap. The user has the option of
        // using the original RGB or the new and improved Log HSV system.

        if (!bUseHSV)
        {
            // The old RGB system.
            P->BitmapData[Pixel] = ReverseRGBBytes
            ((COLORREF)(-16777215.0 / max_iterations * iteration + 16777215.0));
        }
        else
        {
            // The new HSV system.
            sRGB rgb;
            sHSV hsv;
            hsv = mandelbrotHSV(iteration, max_iterations);
            rgb = hsv2rgb(hsv);
            P->BitmapData[Pixel] =
                (((int)(rgb.r * 255)))       +
                (((int)(rgb.g * 255)) <<  8) +
                (((int)(rgb.b * 255)) << 16   );
        }
    }
    // End of thread execution. The return value is available
    // to the invoking thread, but we don't presently use it.

    return 0;
```

And this is the thread dispatcher...

```
        // Parameters for each thread.
        typedef struct ThreadProcParameters
        {
            int       StartPixel;
            int       EndPixel;
            int       yMaxPixel;
            int       xMaxPixel;
            uint32_t* BitmapData;
            double    dxMin;
            double    dxMax;
            double    dyMin;
            double    dyMax;
        } THREADPROCPARAMETERS, *PTHREADPROCPARAMETERS;

        // Allocate per thread parameter and handle arrays.
        PTHREADPROCPARAMETERS* pThreadProcParameters = new PTHREADPROCPARAMETERS[Slices];
        HANDLE* phThreadArray = new HANDLE[Slices];

        // MaxPixel is the total pixel count among all threads.
        int MaxPixel = (rect.bottom - tm.tmHeight) * rect.right;
        int StartPixel, EndPixel, Slice;

        // Main thread dispatch loop. Walk the start and end pixel indices.
        for (StartPixel = 0, EndPixel = PixelStepSize, Slice = 0;
            (EndPixel <= MaxPixel) && (Slice < Slices);
            StartPixel += PixelStepSize, EndPixel = min(EndPixel + PixelStepSize, MaxPixel), ++Slice)
        {
            // Allocate the parameter structure for this thread.
            pThreadProcParameters[Slice] =
                (PTHREADPROCPARAMETERS)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(),
                    HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, sizeof(THREADPROCPARAMETERS));
            if (pThreadProcParameters[Slice] == NULL) ExitProcess(2);

            // Initialize the parameters for this thread.
            pThreadProcParameters[Slice]->StartPixel = StartPixel;
            pThreadProcParameters[Slice]->EndPixel   = EndPixel;
            pThreadProcParameters[Slice]->yMaxPixel  = rect.bottom - tm.tmHeight; // Leave room for the status bar.
            pThreadProcParameters[Slice]->xMaxPixel  = rect.right;
            pThreadProcParameters[Slice]->BitmapData = BitmapData; // Bitmap is shared among all threads.
            pThreadProcParameters[Slice]->dxMin      = dxMin;
            pThreadProcParameters[Slice]->dxMax      = dxMax;
            pThreadProcParameters[Slice]->dyMin      = dyMin;
            pThreadProcParameters[Slice]->dyMax      = dyMax;

            // Create and launch this thread.
            phThreadArray[Slice] = CreateThread
                (NULL, 0, MandelbrotWorkerThread, pThreadProcParameters[Slice], 0, NULL);
            if (phThreadArray[Slice] == NULL)
            {
                ErrorHandler((LPTSTR)_T("CreateThread"));
                ExitProcess(3);
            }
        } // End of main thread dispatch loop.

        // Wait for all threads to terminate.
        WaitForMultipleObjects(Slices, phThreadArray, TRUE, INFINITE);
```

This can be broken up into as many threads as desired. My program, for instance, allows between 1 and 64 threads. For the full program, see https://github.com/alexsokolek2/mandelbrot. Good luck.